# What data issue can cause "AmbiguousBaseClassException: Multiple classes found in type hierarchy that map to [...]"?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Apparently out of the blue, my Springboot/Neo4j application started getting this exception upon startup (around the first time Neo is accessed):

`AmbiguousBaseClassException: Multiple classes found in type hierarchy that map to [Audit, AppInfo]`

After trying various things unsuccessfully, in desperation I dumped the database

(with `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n`)

then restarted.

Suddenly it was working again.  In other words, this error was not due (solely) to code, but to rather to data.

It's as if the "type hierarchy" that is being referred to is something that's being read out of the database, and I seem to have been able to "break it".

Now I'm worried that I can have this pop up out of the blue, at a time when I won't be able to just dump the data.

So how can I work out what causes this, and what less sledgehammer approach would resolve it?

Edit:  I had not originally pasted the specifics of the structure involved, because I had hoped that this was a "class" of problem that could be described, defended against, and diagnosed, without reference to my instance of it.  Maybe this is naive.

Here are the two classes named in the error message:

[definition](https://pastebin.com/eJkwWadM)

[queries](https://pastebin.com/s6kqg2nD)

Edit 2:  The problem recurred today, with a different pair.

[stack trace](https://pastebin.com/baR8Zbxe)

[newly affected node class](https://pastebin.com/MX19Gk1n)

Comment: Can you also add complete exception stack trace when it happens?

Comment: It happened since somehow you attributed two labels to a node in the db (label for Audit, label for AppInfo) so when it tries to load that node it does not know what class to use

Comment: It worths posting some minimal classes structure and stacktrace, queries. Otherwise, we can just "guess"

Comment: @digitalillusion I wonder how we do what you said: how is it that one "attributes two labels to a node?"   Note that this is via spring-data-neo4j ... it would seem almost like a bug in that if this were to happen?

Comment: Update.  I posted, in the question, a stack trace and newly affected pair: TAG, APP_INFO.   I did this query `MATCH (n:TAG) RETURN N` and I got one Tag that had a "schema_id" in it.  This is wrong - schema_id belongs to "APP_INFO".    How can a "user error" of spring_neo_4j possibly write a wrong field to a  node?   I couldn't even write code do do that, I don't think?   Class typing etc would stop me - wouldn't it?

Comment: Whoa - the answer to my question is "easily" :).   I'm pretty sure I have traced down how this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975183/neo4j-sdn4-ogm-ambiguousbaseclassexception) with what may be the same issue. In that particular question, all `Actor` and `Director` nodes in the DB also have the `Person` label. And the developer had mimicked that dual-label situation by implementing `Actor` and `Director` classes that subclassed a `Person` class. As a result, when `PersonRepository.findActorsOfMovie()` is invoked, the OGM library does not know whether to return a `Set` of `Person` instances or `Actor` instances. A similar issue exists with `PersonRepository.findDirectorOfMovie()`. Other methods may not have a similar issue, leading to failures that may appear intermittent (but are actually due to different methods being used for different use cases).

You may have similar issues with your class hierarchy (with respect to your specific DB data model). If so, your OGM method signatures should probably never use the relevant base class.

Comment: @GreenAsJade - Please share the class structure to validate this.

Comment: Thanks for the example!  I added my class definitions, which don't appear to overlap in labels :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.   The accepted answer is correct, but some details, and a different "cause" are laid out in case someone else struggles with it as I did...

**What it is:**

Described in Java/spring-data-neo4j terms, this situation does indeed arise when nodes from two "classes" end up with "properties" that have the same name.

**How it can happen:**

This can (apparently) happen if you have two classes with the same `Property` name, as described in the accepted answer.

But it also it can happen if you continue to use (in Java) a node that has been deleted.

The deleted node is like a pointer to memory that has been freed - if you continue to use it after that, the results are undefined.   And can result in properties from the deleted node being written onto other nodes in the post-deletion save.

**How to find the culprit:**

It seems you will get a pair of classes from the error message.   All you have to do is find the instances from one class that have a property from the other.

In the Neo web browser, I found this as easy as clicking on properties from the class with the least properties, causing it to run the "show me instances that have this property" query.

I didn't have to trawl through every result in the output, because the app kindly lists at the top of the results the number **and type** of nodes with this property.   So all you are doing is looking for one a query that results in more than one type of node, and the culprit is in there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue re stale data. Upgraded ogm lib from 3.0.X to 3.2.1 and the issue went away.